# Blender texture paint problem

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting, texture-painting

I'm starting with sculpting. So after I sculpted I tried to texture paint my model. But there is weird thing: [image: Texture paint]

I'm doing this for a first time and I'm very inexperienced. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Looks like you have your target canvas texture image loaded as your brush texture.Go to your brush texture and see if there is a texture set, remove it if there. Your brush should not be your canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your normals in edit mode. Go into edit mode with the object selected, and show the normals (overlays drop-down, shows you the wee blue lines from the centre of each face).
I'm guessing all the faces that won't take your paint stroke are facing the wrong way- inside the mesh.
[image]